# В чем отличие сигналов для QComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt

Поясните, пожалуйста, отличие между сигналами:

```
void QComboBox::activated(int index)
void QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(int index)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`activated` вызывается в случае, если вы выбрали новое значение из выпадающего списка, (!) в том числе то же самое, что уже было выбрано.

`currentIndexChanged` вызывается только при установке значения, отличного от текущего. Также вызывается, когда значение изменяется программно через вызов `setCurrentIndex`, но опять же только когда значение отлично от текущего.